# How would the discovery of Higgs Boson affect superstring theories?

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, higgs

As we probably all know, a new particle similar to Higgs Boson has been discovered.

If this turns out to be true, standard model will get a boost (as the discovered mass almost equals to the prediction of standard model).

My question is what is the mass of higgs boson that superstring theories predict, and how would this discovery and its data affect superstring theories.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31242/2451

Answer (score 5):

In the slides of this [talk](http://absuploads.aps.org/presentation.cfm?pid=10351), Prof. Gordon Kane explains about a year ago how he and his colleagues obtain a higgs of about 125 GeV from their M-theory phenomenological model for example (slide 20). But string phenomenology is a whole industry now ...

As explained [here](http://motls.blogspot.com/2012/06/higgs-boson-scalar-fields-and-victory.html) the higgs is the first spinless particle experimentally discovered. Since string theory contains many scalar fields (I`m among them :-P ...) it can be interpretted (optimistically) as a hint that string theory is on the right track. In addition, the article contains three cool ways to look at the higgs boson from a stringy point of view.