# Recent Higgs boson observation and credibility of superstring theories

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, higgs

Data are coming in, and it seems that recent Higgs boson observation is eliminating many SUSY models. If so, what is happening to superstring theories, like M-theory?

Comment: There's no problem neither for SUSY nor for ST with the higgs that is found, on the contrary ... ;-). You seem to have completely wrong informations.

Comment: No.. discovery itself isn't the problem, but the data...

Comment: No, you are wrong. See for example [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31348/2751). And the data, meaning the low mass of the higgs discovered, point to the fact that SUSY (or something that does a similar good job) is even [NEEDED](http://motls.blogspot.com/2012/10/higgs-living-near-cliff-of-instability.html?m=1) to stabilize the higgs. I'm really wondering from what sources you take your informations, they are completely wrong.

Comment: Here (http://www.livescience.com/24858-higgs-boson-lhc-particle.html), here (http://www.science20.com/quantum_diaries_survivor/higgs_new_atlas_and_cms_results-96412), and most importantly here (http://www.newscientist.com/article/mg21628923.800-higgs-boson-is-too-saintly-and-supersymmetry-too-shy.html). I know that SUSY is the best and probably the only option to stabilize higgs. However, the data seem to show that some SUSY models are not the right way. (This definitely does not mean that all SUSY models are wrong.) So what about superstring theories? That's what I am asking.

Comment: The standard model is in principle derivable as an effective low energy theory from ST, even though people do not yet know how to extract the complete SM in this way. So this higgs observed should not be a problem either. Being the first particle with zero spin observed it is rather, as explained in the one link I have given, a good thing for ST, since such a spin zero particle (ST predicts many more of them) is finally observed to exist.

Comment: Physicists who know what they are talking about and really work on such topics do often hot agree with what Tommaso Dorigo writes about SUSY, ST, and the possibility for new physics to exist somewhere. He is often overly pessimistic which is not really motivated by the data we have obtained so far. In popular news articles, things are often not described correctly, such that professionals who really work on these things disagree with what is stated.

Comment: @Dilaton:  I hope you're not implying that Dorigo doesn't know what he's talking about.  He's an excellent experimentalist, and he's quite right to say that the vanilla Standard Model does a good job of fitting the data we have right now.

Comment: @user1504 Of course not, that part holds only sometimes for the writers of articles in popular media. Tommaso Dorigo is certainly I great physicist who KNOWS what he is talking about. But for my stomach, his blog posts involving SUSY and its existance in principle for example, are often much to pessimistic (compared to what other physicists say) and more often than not even unnecessarily confrontative and scornful. That is why I have stopped klicking his blog.

Comment: I would like to stress that all the exclusions of this that and the other are at very low significance, one or two sigma, in contrast with the demands for discovery ( five sigma). Exclusion regions are a safe game  experimental physicists and phenomenologists play when they have worked hard and found nothing significant. They have to publish something, theseis are hanging on the publication etc.

Comment: @Dilaton how are you qualified to say which physicists are right and which are wrong? I'm under the impression that Kane expected SUSY to show up in the LEP - it didn't. So the models were modified and so SUSY was expected to show up in the LHC by now. It hasn't, and on we go...

Comment: @The experts know that there are many different kinds of supersymmetric models, not that supersymmetry is not a theory, it is a symmetry a theory with a corresponding Lagrangian can posses or not. It is not known at which energy scale supersymmetry is broken (if it exists) if id does not show up at the LHC this will rule out additional supersymmetric models of course but this would not mean it does not exist at any scale at all. Maybe you should read Prof. Strassler's site, he says too that it is very important to distinguish the ruling out of certain variations of how this symmetry can be

Comment: implemented, and disproving the whole idea in general wrong. That is what many non experts out in the world wild web get often wrong at it is often blatantly misstated by people who have an interest in distorting the public perception of physics too.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is that the TeV scale data we are getting at LHC doesn't tell us anything about string theory.  Which is too bad for string theorists, because they had high hopes.

They had high hopes for the following reason:  If we had found that TeV scale physics is governed by a supersymmetric extension of the Standard Model, we would have strong reason to suspect that the effective field theory which incorporates gravity and the Standard Model is actually a supergravity theory.  Basically, we know that we live in a curved spacetime, and the only natural way to get a global supersymmetry in this situation is to have local supersymmetry, which implies supergravity.  This is pretty exciting, because all of the known supergravity theories are low energy limits of string theory.

Unfortunately, not finding supersymmetry at $1$ TeV doesn't tell us that string theory is wrong.  String theory seems to require supersymmetry at extremely high energies, like the Planck scale, which is roughly $10^{16}$ TeV.  But it doesn't require supersymmetry at $1$ TeV.  (This is not to say that string *theorists* haven't predicted supersymmetry at LHC.  Some theorists make more predictions than their theories do.)

So string theory remains what it has always been:  a fascinating enigma, apparently able to explain all of physics, but refusing to actually do so.

Comment: Ha ha, _Some theorists make more predictions than their theories do._ made me LOL, nice answer +1

Comment: LOLs seconded!!